# Como colocar espaço antes da variável SET /P em Batch?

Tags: windows, script, batch, powershell

Pretendo definir a variável a meio da tela, mas não a consigo colocar!

```
|____não_funciona____|set /p variável=um    
|____funciona____|%variável%
```

Desde já obrigado!

Comment: Não entendi, poderia explicar de outra forma?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Lamento, mas não é possível definir variáveis no Batch começando o
>   valor com espaços. você até consegue defini-las, mas os espaços serão automaticamente removidos.
>
> mas há uma forma de fazer isso, usando um utilitário externo, o **Editv**
>
> você vai jogar o utilitário na sua pasta *"System32"* para o prompt
>   reconhecer o comando do utilitário, ou se preferir, deixe na mesma
>   pasta do Batch que será executado o comando, de preferência oculto,
>   para que não seja apagado acidentalmente.
>
> feito uma dessas opções, use-o da seguinte forma:
>
> `Editv32 -p "Qual o seu nome?" nome`
>
> preste bastante atenção, O Comando **Editv32** tem que ser o mesmo nome do
>   utilitário que você jogou na pasta *System32*, sem a necessidade de usar
>   a extensão .exe
>
> se você renomea-lo para **Edit** por exemplo, terá de usar assim:
>
> ```
> `Edit -p "Qual o seu nome?" nome
> ```
>
> o *"nome"* no final do comando, é o nome da variável que você vai chamar dentro de %%.
>
> Essa linha de comando esperará por uma entrada do usuário, e é aí que
>   você vai colocar o tanto de espaços que quiser antes de digitar o
>   valor da variável. e quando você chamar a variável com %%, ela será
>   impressa com os espaços na frente.
>
> `-p` te permite informar algo na tela, como uma pergunta por exemplo, sempre em aspas duplas.
>
> `-l` te permite limitar o numero de caracteres que terá o valor da variável.
>
> **exemplo:** `-l 10` Indica que o usuário so conseguirá digitar 10 caracteres para o valor da variável.
>
> `-n` força o usuário a usar apenas números no valor da variável.
>
> `-m` vai mascarar o valor da variável em asteriscos. *(utilizado para senhas)*
>
> `-t 04` inicia uma contagem de 4 segundos, *(apenas um exemplo)*

Esse é o site onde você encontra o Pacote com os dois utilitários

o **Editv32** para sistemas 32bits
e o **Editv64** para sistemas 64bits

http://www.westmesatech.com/editv.html

Comment: Boa! Desconhecia por completo essa alternativa... obrigado!